# How to adjust the font size for axis labels in Complex Heatmap?

Tags: r, plot, heatmap, axis-labels, bioconductor

I'm using [ComplexHeatmap](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/manuals/ComplexHeatmap/man/ComplexHeatmap.pdf) to create a heatmap in R.  I have recreated a small heatmap here.  I can't figure out from the documentation how to adjust the font size for the text on the x-axis.

```
a = matrix(1:9, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
rownames(a) = c("alphabet","xylophone","tornado")
colnames(a) = c("c1","c2","c3")

my_heatmap = ComplexHeatmap::Heatmap(
        matrix = t(a),
        col = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(9, "RdBu"))
```

This code produces this:

[image: Heatmap]

I want to adjust the font size for the `c("alphabet","xylophone","tornado")` text so that it is much smaller.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `row_names_gp` and `column_names_gp` to adjust y-axis and x-axis labels, respectively.

```
# if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
#       install.packages("BiocManager")
# BiocManager::install("ComplexHeatmap")
#
# library(ComplexHeatmap)
# library(grid)
```

```r
a = matrix(1:9, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
rownames(a) = c("alphabet","xylophone","tornado")
colnames(a) = c("c1","c2","c3")

ComplexHeatmap::Heatmap(
  matrix = t(a),
  col = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(9, "RdBu"),
  column_names_gp = grid::gpar(fontsize = 8),
  row_names_gp = grid::gpar(fontsize = 8))
```

[image]